# Proving Gaussian integers have non unique quotient and remainder in division algorithm.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gaussian-integers

As given in the book by Pollard, Diamond, on Algebraic Numbers, there is proof for division algorithm being made to work for Gaussian integers, with the above as an exercise left to the reader to prove by an example, as shown below in pg. 8,9 of the book.

But, I am unable to theoretically imagine the significance (say, by relation of lattice points of one set of the two values, to another set) and the cause of non-uniqueness being there in Gaussian integers (and hence in all algebraic integers), & so feel that an example would be understandable or workable by me, once I can derive the proof of the same.

[image]

However, there is an example copied from [example at page 6 of this](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jverstra/Gaussian1.pdf), that states example of dividend of $3+2i$, divisor of $-1+3i$, and states that as long as the norm of the remainder is less than that of the norm of divisor. The example has dividend as : $3 + 2i$ with norm = $13$, divisor as : $-1 + 3i$ with norm = $10$, and multiplying the fraction with conjugate of the denominator(divisor) yielding : $\frac{3}{10} + i\frac{-11}{10}$.

The first set of values derived is : $q = -i, r = i$. There is derivation of the first set of values by a similar mechanism to that stated in the book, but it is not clear that how the ratio of $3/10$ being closer to $0$, & of $-11/10$ being closer to $-1$ leads to quotient of $-i$.

The alternate value set suggested is: $q = 1-i$, $r= 1-2i$, as the norm of remainder $\lt$ than that of divisor.
 $(-1 + 3i)(1-i) + (1-2i) \implies (-1 +4i +4) + (1 -2i) = 3 +2i$. There is no clue to me how to check for different such quotients. Can I take any quotient with $N_q \lt N_b$, ($b$ standing for divisor), and being a rational expression will succeed. So, the first step should be the check of dividend being not a prime. But, how? I mean the check should be $(a+bi)(x+yi) = 3 + 2i$, and its conjugate $(a-bi)(x-yi) = 3 - 2i, \exists a,b,x,y \in \mathbb {Z}$. This should lead to :$$
\begin{align}
& (a+bi)(x+yi) = 3 + 2i  & \  (a-bi)(x-yi) = 3 - 2i \\
& ax - by =3, ay + bx =2  & \  ax -by =3, ay + bx = 2 \\
\end{align}
$$ On multiplying the two conjugates on both the $lhs$ and $rhs$ lead to :
$(a^2 + b^2)(x^2 + y^2) =13$  which to me leads nowhere, as the dividend should not be a prime, but cannot find two non-unit factors of $13$.

Please tell me where I am wrong, as it is not possible to consider the ratio of $a/b$ to be considered for checking primality. So, what is wrong? Totally confused!

---

Also, as earlier stated without a proof, or understanding the significance in terms of lattice points, it is banal to find solutions for quotient and remainder.

Comment: You write "but it is not clear how the ratio of $\frac{3}{10}$ being closer to $0$, and of $\frac{-11}{10}$ being closer to $-1$ leads to a quotient of $-i$".  But it should be clear that, in a naive sense, this means $\frac{3}{10} + i \frac{-11}{10}$ is close to $0 + i(-1)$, which is the same as $-i$.

Comment: @ErickWong Okay, that was foolish to be confused. But, how the logic for the second set of values came in really confusing.

Comment: We approximate the quotient (in $\mathbb{Q}[i]$), $z = \frac{3}{10} - i\frac{11}{10}$, with a Gaussian integer $q = a + ib$ such that $\lvert z - q\rvert^2 < 1$. That implies $\lvert a - \frac{3}{10}\rvert < 1$ and $\lvert b - \frac{11}{10}\rvert < 1$, so we have the choices $a \in \{0,1\}$ and $b \in \{1,2\}$. Three of these choices give a $q$ close enough to $z$, only $a = 1,\, b = 2$ doesn't.

Comment: @DanielFischer Cool algebraic way, thanks for that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Regarding the second solution, if could please help in proving that the dividend is not prime. My approach is  $ (a+bi)(x+yi) = 3 + 2i,  (a-bi)(x-yi) = 3 - 2i \implies (a^2 + b^2)(x^2 + y^2) =13$ which to me leads nowhere, as $13$ cannot be factorized into product of two non-unit factors.

Comment: But $3 + 2i$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Consider the norm (not a norm in the functional analysis sense, a norm in the algebra sense) $N(x+iy) = x^2 + y^2 = \lvert x+iy\rvert^2 = (x+iy)\cdot \overline{(x+iy)}$. Clearly we have $N(\omega) \in \mathbb{N}$ (which is taken to include $0$) for all $\omega \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, and $N(\omega\cdot \zeta) = N(\omega)\cdot N(\zeta)$. It's not hard to see that $\zeta$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ if and only if $N(\zeta) = 1$. It follows that every $\omega\in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $N(\omega)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: For if $\omega = \zeta\cdot \eta$, then $N(\omega) = N(\zeta)\cdot N(\eta)$, and since $N(\omega)$ is prime, it follows that $N(\zeta) = N(\omega)$ and $N(\eta) = 1$ or $N(\zeta) = 1$ and $N(\eta) = N(\omega)$. So one of the factors is necessarily a unit. Then, since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a Euclidean domain, it follows that $\omega$, being irreducible, is prime. Since $N(3+2i) = 3^2 + 2^2 = 13$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, it thus follows that $3+2i$ is prime.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, but can we divide a prime then. Then what is the significance of primes in algebraic integers? The division algorithm should not have given any value of quotient and remainder for a prime.

Comment: @DanielFischer sorry for a non-intuitive question in my last comment.

Comment: Why not? We can compute the quotient and remainder of the division of the prime $13$ by the composite $8$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, and we do that quite often (not necessarily with these exact numbers). The dividend being prime or not is irrelevant for the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am both thankful and sorry.

Comment: Thankful makes sense. But why would you be sorry? [In the context of this question and the comments here. In other contexts, I would imagine you probably have more or less the usual amount of reasons to be sorry; like for not writing aunt Bess a postcard from your vacations.]